# Output an array of numbers without having to output each value in it separately?

Tags: c++

I have outputted each value in the array by "cout" numbers[1], numbers[2], and so on. I want to know if it's possible to "cout" just one value representing all the numbers in the array at once.

```
int numbers [ ] = { 40, 20, 50, 60, 10, 15 } ;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a loop, e.g.

```
for( int const x : numbers )
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: By the way, `endl` can be replaced with `" "`, `", "`, or any separator you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::copy()` with the `std::begin()` and `std::end()` helper functions to create a range for your array. Then you use `std::ostream_iterator<int>` to place the output:

```c++
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::copy(std::begin(numbers),
          std::end(numbers), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));
```